# EditItemTemplate with DropDownList - onselectedindexchanged

Tags: c#, asp.net

Within my EditTemplate I have a DropDownList as such:

```
<EditItemTemplate>                      
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFixture" runat="server"   AutoPostBack="True"   onselectedindexchanged="fixtureSelected"
           DataSourceID="FixtureDataSource"  DataTextField="WTag" DataValueField="WTag" AppendDataBoundItems="true" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Fixure") %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>                                                         
</EditItemTemplate>
```

When the user selects an item from the DropDownList, I like to populate other fields in that are in EditMode as well.

You will notice that on onselectedindexchanged="fixtureSelected" I am calling fixtureSelected. I have noted some of the issues I am facing:

```
protected void fixtureSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Below I am trying to get value of ddlFixture but it cannot recognize ddlFixture. GettingThe name 'ddlFixture' does not exist in the current context

     string fixtureId = ddlFixture.SelectedItem.Value;

    // I also need to update the text in EditMode but this will not work either. Get similar message as for ddlFixture 

    txtCampus.Text = "Campus1";             
}
```

Comment: I think the sender parameter will contain your object reference to 'dllFixture'.

Comment: Have you tried using FindControl like below?      DropDownList ddlFixture = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlFixture");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is due to the fact that the controls your are trying to access are inside the edititemtemplate of your GridView.

To get to the dropdownlist instance, you can use:

```
DropDownList ddlFixture = sender as DropDownList;
```

And to get the other controls in edititemtemplate, you use:

```
ddlFixture.NamingContainer.FindControl("control_id")
```

For example:

```
TextBox txtCampus = ddlFixture.NamingContainer.FindControl("txtCampus") as TextBox;
```

Comment: Uros, I could not undertand why we want ddlFixture when trying to get the value of txtCampus. I changed it to the following but not working:  TextBox txtCampus = RadGrid1.FindControl("txtCampus") as TextBox; I get a message that txtCamus is null

Comment: Did you try the code I suggest? Through ddlFixture's NamingContainer and FindControl you get to instances of other controls inside edititemtemplate. FindControl searches control only inside a NamingContainer, which is why your code above doesn't work